# How to remove # keyword from a listing style?

Tags: listings, keywords

I have a snippet of code I'm putting into a paper written in LaTeX.

I don't want it to highlight any of the keywords that start with a # sign, such as #define, or #pragma. Here is a MWE of what I have right now:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\newcommand{\us}{\char`_}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\lstdefinestyle{cpp_onecol}{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    morekeywords={CHECK},
    keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries\itshape,
    commentstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
    alsoother={\#},
    deletekeywords ={\#pragma}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=cpp_onecol]
#pragma hello
#define I_DONT_LIKE_POUNDSIGN 1

int a;
int b;
volatile int c;   

\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Stupid hashtag.]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

This generates:

[image: Pound sign still highlighting.]

I have tried searching for a solution, but I think the # is ruining my search results too. The only one I found suggested adding the `alsoother={\#},` but that didn't really help at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I added a deletedelim with a pound sign.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}

\newcommand{\us}{\char`_}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{float}
\lstdefinestyle{cpp_onecol}{
    language = C++,
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
    breaklines=true,
    morekeywords={CHECK},
    keywordstyle=\color{black}\bfseries\itshape,
    commentstyle=\color{black}\bfseries,
    alsoother={\#},
    deletekeywords ={\#pragma},
    deletedelim=*[directive]\#
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=cpp_onecol]
#pragma hello
#define I_DONT_LIKE_POUNDSIGN 1

int a;
int b;
volatile int c;  

// Hello! 

\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption=Stupid hashtag.]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: Fixed it!]